# Is the identity of the planet in the start and ending of Cloud Atlas canonically known?

Tags: cloud-atlas

In the start and ending of Cloud Atlas, Zachry (Tom Hanks) is shown on another planet, which has two moons and from which the Earth can be seen.

[image]

[image]

Is there any canonical identity given to this planet? Terraformed Mars would be a decent option, but the moons do not match Phobos and Deimos in size.

Comment: Neither the Wikipedia article nor the Cloud Atlas Wikia have a quoted location for those scenes.... and the scenes don't seem to have occurred in the book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't appear to have a canonical name, [Wikipedia identifies the location as an off world colony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_Atlas_%28film%29) and the [cited links](http://www.vulture.com/2012/10/guide-to-the-characters-and-connections-of-cloud-atlas-confused.html) for the below quote name every location except the location used in the epilogue:

> A seventh time period, several decades after the events on Big Island, is featured in the film's prologue and epilogue: Zachry is revealed to have been telling these stories to his grandchildren on a beach near a city on an extraterrestrial Earth colony. The epilogue also confirms that Meronym succeeded in sending the message and traveled to the off-world colony where she lives with Zachry.

This text is basically mirrored on the [Cloud Atlas Wikia](http://cloudatlas.wikia.com/wiki/Cloud_Atlas_(film)).